# Add custom menu item on wordpress 3.9.1 media upload

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js

I'm trying to add a menu item on Media Uploader of WordPress.

It is like this screenshot: [image]

Basically, it should have the same functionality of `Create Gallery` with just different shortcode output.

I've search Google for hours now and this has the closest thing of what I want: https://gist.github.com/Fab1en/4586865

But it has an error which I can't figure out. (I have no knowledge on `Backbone.js`)

```
// create an input
this.input = this.make( 'input', { // error line
    type:  'text',
    value: this.model.get('custom_data')
});
```

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I think, if this will be fixed, everything will be good to go...

Is there anyone who have tried this one? I need some help.

Comment: That's not specifically backbone, but javascript: `this.model.get` is `undefined` and as the error message tells you (you should also know this), `undefined` is not a function in javascript. And please only ask about your own code on stackoverflow, we can not do your third-party code integration needs here, that is off-topic. I also report this question because a bounty has been placed which prevents it from being closed.

Comment: I beg to differ. All I say is that *if* `this.make` is `undefined` (which is what you say) *then* `this.make` is not backbone, because it is `undefined`. You probably want it to be backbone, that might be, however it is not. It's just `undefined` in javascript. As backbone does not come in by wanting only (the magic), it's perhaps worth you differentiate here a bit more so that it's clear where the cause of your error defining backbone might be.

Comment: Save the hassle @hakre if you don't intend to help. Anyway, I think there's a problem with `this.make()` of `backbone`. Maybe it's deprecated or something. I got it working when I changed that line of codes to equivalent of jQuery. Which is `this.input = jQuery( '<input type="text">').val(this.model.get('slideshow_data'));` It's not showing the error now. But I won't close this question until someone can give me the answer. I'm still not satisfied with my findings.

Comment: Can you show us your code to make the 'gallery' shortcode for your Create Slideshow? Basically what happens after the user selects their images?

Comment: What @hakre is trying to say (not very elegantly) is that the "this" keyword is clearly out of context and is not referring to Backbone.  Whoever wrote the code is expecting the code to be running in a context where "this" === Backbone... but it's not, and we can't troublshoot it for you.  Contact the plugin author, or at least post some code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @RyanWheale it's not out of context... even this test I found on the net is giving an error on `this.make()`. http://jsperf.com/backbone-view-make-vs-jquery-elem/2

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function custom_media_upload_tab_name( $tabs ) {
    $newtab = array( 'tab_slug' => 'Your Tab Name' );
    return array_merge( $tabs, $newtab );
}

add_filter( 'media_upload_tabs', 'custom_media_upload_tab_name' );

function custom_media_upload_tab_content() {
    // Add you content here.
}
add_action( 'media_upload_tab_slug', 'custom_media_upload_tab_content' );
```